# Custom colors when generating a pie chart from JSON

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to create a pie chart with a custom set of colours using Am4Charts and the createFromConfig method.

I've followed the tutorial [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/json-config/#Structure_of_JSON_config) but the chart keeps appearing with it's default color set.

Here is a sample of the JSON I've tried:

```
"innerRadius": 100,
"colors": {"list": ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff" ]},
"data": {
  "0": {
    "pot": "Within 8 days",
    "value": "£111,119.70",
  },
  "1": {
    "pot": "9 - 17 days",
    "value": "£225,537.73"
  },
"2": {
    "pot": "18+ days",
    "value": "£720,279.85"
}
},
"legend": [],
"xAxes": [
{
    "type": "CategoryAxis",
    "title": {
    "text": "pot"
    },
    "dataFields": {
    "category": "pot",
    "title": {
        "text": "Month"
    }
    },
    "renderer": {
    "labels": {
        "rotation": 190,
        "verticalCenter": "middle",
        "horizontalCenter": "left"
    }
    }
}
],

"series": [
{
    "type": "PieSeries",
    "dataFields": {
    "value": "value",
    "category": "pot"
    },
    "ticks": {
    "disabled": true
    },
    "labels": {
    "disabled": true
    },

}
],
```

Can somebody see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2:

> Fixed in 4.0.0-beta.85.
>
> Make sure you clear your browser cache after upgrading. And feel free to contact us again if you are still experiencing this issue.

### Update 1:

Response from `amchart` contributor/CTO Martynas Majeris (https://github.com/martynasma):

> Looks like there are two issues: documentation is wrong and there's a bug that prevents it from working :)
>
> I updated the docs. It should say this:
>
> ```
> {
>     // ...
>     "series": [{
>         // ...
>         "colors": {
>             "list": [
>                 "#845EC2",
>                 "#D65DB1",
>                 "#FF6F91",
>                 "#FF9671",
>                 "#FFC75F",
>                 "#F9F871"
>             ]
>         }
>     }]    
> }
> ```
>
> Also, fixed bug in dev version. New version will be released within 1-2 days.

### Original

This might be a bug and I have opened an issue on `amchart` github. I will update this once I get a response: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/577

By the way, I do think your configuration JSON has couple issues:

- `data` is an array, not an object
- `legend` is an object, not an array

This is what I used to create the pie chart demo for the opened issue:

```
// Create chart instance in one go
let chart = am4core.createFromConfig({
    "colors": {
        "list": ["#ff0000","#00ff00", "#0000ff"]
    },
    // Create pie series
    "series": [{
        "colors": ["#ff0000","#00ff00", "#0000ff"],
        "type": "PieSeries",
        "dataFields": {
            "value": "value",
            "category": "pot"
        }
    }],
    // Add data
    "data": [{
        "pot": "Within 8 days",
        "value": "£111,119.70"
    }, {
        "pot": "9 - 17 days",
        "value": "£225,537.73"
    }, {
        "pot": "18+ days",
        "value": "£720,279.85"
    }],
    // Add legend
    "legend": {},
    "innerRadius": 100
}, "chart", am4charts.PieChart);
```